# (C++) Cannot refer to an enum class inside a namespace

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces

Hello I met this problem during a project, I have something like this:

types.h

```
namespace Machine
{
    enum class size{
        TINY,
        SMALL,
        MEDIUM
    }
    //other stuff.....
```

and in another file:

test.h:

```
#include "types.h"
class sample{
    public:
        void some_function();
        Machine::size s; //this declaration is correct
}
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"
void some_function(){
    s = Machine::size::TINY;//line aaaa; this line is error
}
```

at line aaaa I kept getting the error message:

> error: 'Machine::size' is not a class or namespace

Anyone have any idea why? Or is it not good to put enum class inside a namespace? 
Thanks!

> Edit: I fixed the machine spell problem in the first file, sorry about
>   that

Machine::size s is just a place to hold this attribute (the size of a machine), so I don't really think it's something special.

Comment: In your first file machine is underscore. Is it intended

Comment: Please don't fix your question using the accepted answer.  It makes it very confusing to anyone who reads this later.  I have rolled back to a previous revision so that the question and answer make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **test.cpp** replace the definition starting with

```
void some_function()
```

by

```
void sample::some_function()
```

as otherwise you are defining a free standing function with no relation whatsoever with the class `sample` (in other words, you are not defining a member function). So in your case `s` is not seen as a member variable of the class `sample`, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks! But if that part is also correct, this error should not happen right?

Comment: @Wenyu No, it should work, and it works (tested on my side). Make a minimal example and make sure you compile it correctly, including `-std=c++11` compiler flag if you use C++11 with gcc/clang.

Comment: @Wenyu If it works now, please revert the edit, as now the code in your question looks completely correct and the answer seem to address an non-existing issue.

Comment: @vsoftco Oh, I already did that after coming across this question and being puzzled by it.